# Function returning undefined when it should be called from footer.php

Tags: php, javascript

I'm working on an online quoting system (from scratch) and am getting an exception due to something in my PHP footer.

When the user clicks Submit, the call to functions in the MMJS/MPJS/DPJS documents (near the end of the code below) goes through only if the block of calls to the SQL database is commented out as illustrated below. Otherwise, I get an exception saying the functions in those documents are undefined.

Why does this code block cause functions in documents called later on to be unreachable?

Code:

```
        <div id="results"></div>

        </div><!-- #wrapper -->

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="<?PHP echo $relpath; ?>js/vendor/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <script src="<?PHP echo $relpath; ?>js/plugins.js"></script>
        <script src="<?PHP echo $relpath; ?>js/main.js"></script>

        // <script type="text/javascript">
            // <?PHP
                // $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM `Fixed Quoter Prices` WHERE 1");
                // $stmt->bind_result($db_DPbaseRate, $db_MPbaseRate, $db_MMbaseRate, $db_raidRate, $db_boxRate, $db_metaRate, $db_sanRate,$db_hbaRate, $db_twoTB, $db_threeTB, $db_fourTB, $db_switchUpgrade, $db_tenRate, $db_taxRate);
                // $stmt->execute();
                // $stmt->fetch();

                // echo "var DPbaseRate = $db_DPbaseRate;";
                // echo "var MPbaseRate = $db_MPbaseRate;";
                // echo "var MMbaseRate = $db_MMbaseRate;";
                // echo "var raidRate = $db_raidRate;";
                // echo "var boxRate = $db_boxRate;";
                // echo "var metaRate = $db_metaRate;";
                // echo "var sanRate = $db_sanRate;";
                // echo "var hbaRate = $db_hbaRate;";
                // echo "var twoTB = $db_twoTB;";
                // echo "var threeTB = $db_threeTB;";
                // echo "var fourTB = $db_fourTB;";
                // echo "var switchUpgrade = $db_switchUpgrade;";
                // echo "var tenRate = $db_tenRate;";
                // echo "var taxRate = $db_taxRate;";
            // ?>

        // </script>

        <?PHP if($title == 'Media Master') : ?>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/MMJS.js"></script>
        <?PHP elseif($title == 'Media Pro') : ?>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/MPJS.js"></script>
        <?PHP elseif($title == 'Desk Pro') : ?>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/DPJS.js"></script>
        <?PHP endif; ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! I forgot my initial SQL database connection.

Corrected inner script with added line in blockquote:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            <?PHP
```

> $mysqli = new mysqli('12.34.56.78','someuser','somepass','foo');

```
                $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM `Fixed Quoter Prices` WHERE 1");
                $stmt->bind_result($db_DPbaseRate, $db_MPbaseRate, $db_MMbaseRate, $db_raidRate, $db_boxRate, $db_metaRate, $db_sanRate,$db_hbaRate, $db_twoTB, $db_threeTB, $db_fourTB, $db_switchUpgrade, $db_tenRate, $db_taxRate);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->fetch();

                echo "var DPbaseRate = $db_DPbaseRate;";
                echo "var MPbaseRate = $db_MPbaseRate;";
                echo "var MMbaseRate = $db_MMbaseRate;";
                echo "var raidRate = $db_raidRate;";
                echo "var boxRate = $db_boxRate;";
                echo "var metaRate = $db_metaRate;";
                echo "var sanRate = $db_sanRate;";
                echo "var hbaRate = $db_hbaRate;";
                echo "var twoTB = $db_twoTB;";
                echo "var threeTB = $db_threeTB;";
                echo "var fourTB = $db_fourTB;";
                echo "var switchUpgrade = $db_switchUpgrade;";
                echo "var tenRate = $db_tenRate;";
                echo "var taxRate = $db_taxRate;";
            ?>
        </script>
```